# How to implement ln(x) in a flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, math, integer, double

how can I Implement the ln(x) in flutter? Can I use Math package?

I know that ln(x) = Loge(x)

Not found package to do that for me

Answer (score 0):

Use `import 'dart:math';`.

See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-math/dart-math-library.html

Answer (score 0):

The [`log` function from `dart:math`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-math/log.html) already gives you the natural logarithm:

> Converts `x` to a `double` and returns the natural logarithm of the value.

And you can easily verify that `log(e)` returns `1.0`.